# Javascript conditional method chaining

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, method-chaining

How can I simplify this code to use conditional method chaining for useBuffer() method. Please suggest.

```
  const getApi = async (headers, userContext, httpRequest, url, isBlob) => {
  if (isBlob) {
    const result = await httpRequest
      .get(url)
      .withCredentials()
      .set(headers)
      .send({ userContext })
      .useBuffer()
      .then((res) => [res.body, res.headers]);
    return result;
  }
  else {
    const result = await httpRequest
      .get(url)
      .withCredentials()
      .set(headers)
      .send({ userContext })
      .then((res) => res);
    return result;
  }
};
```

to something like this:

```
const getApi = async (headers, userContext, httpRequest, url, isBlob) => {
    const result = await httpRequest
      .get(url)
      .withCredentials()
      .set(headers)
      .send({ userContext })
      .isBlob && useBuffer()
      .then((res) => isBlob ? [res.body, res.headers] : res);
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then((res) => res)` is redundant and boolean parameters that control structure are questionable design, so how about:

```js
const getApi = (headers, userContext, httpRequest, url) =>
  httpRequest
    .get(url)
    .withCredentials()
    .set(headers)
    .send({ userContext });

const getApiBlob = (headers, userContext, httpRequest, url) =>
  getApi(headers, userContext, httpRequest, url)
    .useBuffer()
    .then((res) => [res.body, res.headers]);
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. This was much cleaner . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about saving the earlier chain in a variable?

```
const getApi = async (headers, userContext, httpRequest, url, isBlob) => {
    const sent = await httpRequest
        .get(url)
        .withCredentials()
        .set(headers)
        .send({ userContext })
    return !isBlob
        ? sent
        : sent
            .useBuffer()
            .then((res) => [res.body, res.headers]);
};
```

The `.then((res) => res);` is completely superfluous and so can be removed.

Comment: ".then((res) => res)" comment was very helpful. I was using it at multiple places, so got rid of it eventually. Thanks!